# Test effective permissions of file for user

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to test effective permissions of a file for a specific user?

I normally do this by `su user` and then accessing the file, but I now want to test this on an user with no shell (i.e. a System user)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `sudo` command can run anything as a particular user with the `-u` option. Instead of worrying about shells, just try to `cat` (or execute, whatever) your file as your target user:

```
$ sudo -u apache cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
cat: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

Comment: `cat` is probably not the best choice though... it you are testing a large file or a binary file...

Comment: Your example is flawed though; SSH requires particular permissions set on `.ssh` (`u=rwx,g=,o=`) and its children (`u=rw,g=r,o=r`) or it will refuse to use the entire config for that user. This does not test that.

Answer (score 33):

I found  convenient to use in scripts something like

```
 sudo -u <user> test -r <file-to-test> && ...
```

Comment: best answer, as you can test for readable (-r), writable (-w) and executable (-x) without actually modifying/creating the file. `man test` for more details

Comment: And lends itself wonderfully to use in scripts, where you generally need things to be non-interactive.

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo -u <user> test -r <file-to-test>; echo $?
```

The `echo $?` part will output the exit status from the test.

Just remember here that the output will be `0` if the operation was *successful!* Or non-zero, e.g. `1`, if not.

Like [@Thomas's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37000/test-effective-permissions-of-file-for-user#comment226428_136386) on @user72025's answer, use `man test` to get more operation tests, like `test -x` to test executability, `test -w` for writability, etc.

Comment: For me, this is the most helpful answer. The one by user72025 was close, but I had no idea what the result was. You've made that clear. Thanks. Voting up.

Answer (score 6):

I've found you can use `su -s <shellname> <username>` to enter a specific shell as a specific user. You can then test file permissions as usual.

E.g.:

```
su -s /bin/bash Debian-exim
touch /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template
```

Comment: Very interesting option.